# Trying to setup unit testing for Typescript project using Karma

Tags: typescript, karma-runner

I am trying to use Karma to test a NodeJS project written in Typescript. I want to use tsUnit  as the Unit test framework

http://tsunit.codeplex.com/

and the karma-typescript-preprocessor to get karma to compile typescript first.

https://npmjs.org/package/karma-typescript-preprocessor

This is turning out to be a very bumpy ride and I would love to understand the process from anyone who has experience setting up Karma to test Typescript over NodeJS. Even if you have used a different test framework or preprocessor.

Comment: Did you used tsUnit then, or you went for Jasmine?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I just set up a Karma/Typescript test but it's not using Node.js. I'm using Intellij Idea 13 and the Karma plugin, and I followed this process here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CgKU7jTub4

The basic steps are:

1. Set up a watcher to compile your Typescript files as you save them.
2. Set up your Karma setup using Karma init karma.conf.js (I'm using Chrome/Jasmine)
3. Add your js files to the list of files to make sure they're included in the test.
4. Download the Typescript definition for Jasmine/Jasmine-Jquery as a global library.

It wasn't too painful, and Webstorm adds a nice GUI to the whole operation.

Comment: There is only one problem. When one of the tests fails, IntelliJ shows us javascript version of our test. That's very uncomfotable and often causes that we modify the generated javascript code - every change is lost immediately. That's why we write tests for TypeScript classes in JavaScript.

Comment: Keep in mind that a setup that depends on a IDE to be installed is not ideal nor a solution.