# Setup tsUnit with Karma

Tags: typescript, karma-runner

I want to set tsUnit with Karma. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933049/trying-to-setup-unit-testing-for-typescript-project-using-karma) question, but it seems they went for Jasmine.

Does anybody know how to configure Karma with tsUnit?